# Make a c program that will tell if a string is a palindrome(read the same way both ways) until BYE is encountered

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, string-comparison, palindrome

Everything is working in my code but as soon as user inputs "BYE" my program is not ending i don't know why while loop is not responding to that code

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch[20];

    while (ch != "bye")
    {
        scanf("%s", ch);

        int i;
        int n = strlen(ch);
        int c = 0;


        for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            if (ch[i] == ch[n - i - 1])
                c++;
        }
        if (c == i)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (ch != "bye")` compares the addresses of the array `ch` and the string literal, which will never be the same. Use `while (strcmp(ch, "bye") != 0)`.

Comment: `strcmp` ... look it up... your code compares two pointers

Answer (score 0):

For starters the array `ch` was not initialized that is initially it does not contain a string

```
char ch[20];
```

Secondly in the condition of the while loop

```
while (ch != "bye")
```

there are compared two addresses: the address of the first element of the array `ch` and the address of the first element of the string literal `"bye"`. As the array and the string literal occupy different extents of memory the addresses always will be unequal. So as a result you have an infinite loop that does not contain a break statement.

If you want to compare strings then you need to use the standard string function `strcmp` as for example

```
if ( strcmp( ch, "bye" ) == 0 )
{
    //...
}
```

In this case the array `ch` shall already contain a string.

So instead of the while statement it is better to use do-while statement or an infinite while statement that will be interrupted through the break statement if `strcmp` will return 0.

For example

```
while ( 1 )
{
    char ch[20];

    scanf("%19s", ch );

    if ( strcmp( ch, "bye" ) == 0 ) break;
    
    size_t n = strlen(ch);

    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i < n / 2 && ch[i] == ch[n - i - 1] ) ++i;
 
    if ( i == n / 2 )
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");      }
    }  
}
```